# Кроссбраузерность с textarea

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, firefox, textarea

Здравствуйте господа и дамы. У меня есть вопрос касательно тега teaxtarea и фреймворка bootstrap 4.

Суть проблемы такова: в браузерах с движком хрониум (опера и хром) данное текстовое поле работает без проблем:
[image: скриншот 1]

Проверяя на кроссбраузерность, открыл сайт в Mozilla и увидел следующую картину:

[image: скриншот 2]

Ширина textarea ведет себя, мягко говоря, не очень. Ниже прикреплю код со стилями. В чем проблема и как ее можно решить?

```html
<textarea type="text" id="text-area" class="md-textarea form-control" placeholder="Your message" cols="53" rows="6" style="resize: vertical; min-height: 50px; height: 100px; max-height: 150px; background: none; border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid gray; border-radius: 0; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 15px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: <textarea type="text" id="text-area" class="md-textarea form-control" placeholder="Your message" cols="53" rows="6"  style="resize: vertical; min-height: 50px; height: 100px; max-height: 150px;  background: none; border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid gray; border-radius: 0; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 15px;"></textarea>

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено. Нужно было всего лишь добавить max-width:100%; и все заработало.